# Remove specific characters in filename

Tags: bash, awk, sed, suffix

Is there any easy solution how to trim suffix in my filename? Problem is, that my suffix length is vary. Only the same string in filename is _L001.

See the example:

```
NAME-code_code2_L001_sufix
NAME-code_L001_sufix_sufix2_sufix3
NAME-code_code2_code3_L001_sufix_sufix2_sufix3
```

I need to output everything before _L001:

```
NAME-code_code2
NAME-code
NAME-code_code2_code3
```

I was thinking do something like this (when suffix is fixed length):

```
echo NAME-code_code2_L001_sufix | rev | cut -c 12- | rev
```

But of course my suffix length is vary. Is there any bash or awk solution?

Thank you.

Comment: sorry, it was typo. I just edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using pure string manipulation technique:-

```
$ string="NAME-code_code2_L001_sufix"; printf "%s\n" "${string%_L001*}"
NAME-code_code2
```

For all the lines int the file, you can do the same by `bash`, by reading the file in-memory and performing the extraction

```
# Setting a variable to the contents of a file using 'command-substitution'
$ mystringfile="$(<stringfile)"                 

# Read the new-line de-limited string into a bash-array for per-element operation
$ IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra inputArray <<< "$mystringfile"

# Run the sub-string extraction for each entry in the array
$ for eachString in "${inputArray[@]}"; do printf "%s\n" "${eachString%_L001*}"; done

NAME-code_code2
NAME-code
NAME-code_code2_code3
```

You can write the contents to a new-file by modifying the `printf` in the for loop as

```
printf "%s\n" "${eachString%_L001*}" >> output-file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_L001` as field separator in awk and print first field:

```
awk -F '_L001' '{print $1}' file

NAME-code_code2
NAME-code
NAME-code_code2_code3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would propose [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1).

```
sed 's|\(.*\)_L001.*|\1|'
```

example:

```
$ for LINE in NAME-code_code2_L001_sufix NAME-code_L001_sufix_sufix2_sufix3 NAME-code_code2_code3_L001_sufix_sufix2_sufix3; do echo "$LINE"|sed 's|\(.*\)_L001.*|\1|';done
NAME-code_code2
NAME-code
NAME-code_code2_code3
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is `grep` solution: This will print lines from the start till `_L001` is seen.

```
grep -oP '^.*?(?=_L001)' inputfile
NAME-code_code2
NAME-code
NAME-code_code2_code3
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this:

```
# Here is your Input text.
bash$> cat a.txt
NAME-code_code2_L001_sufix
NAME-code_L001_sufix_sufix2_sufix3
NAME-code_code2_code3_L001_sufix_sufix2_sufix3
bash$>

# Desired output using perl.
bash$> cat a.txt |perl -nle 'if (/^(.+)_L.*$/){print $1}'
NAME-code_code2
NAME-code
NAME-code_code2_code3
bash$>

# Desired output using sed.
bash$> cat a.txt |sed 's#\(.*\)_L001_.*#\1#g'
NAME-code_code2
NAME-code
NAME-code_code2_code3
bash$>

# Desired output using cut
bash$> cat a.txt |cut -f1 -d "L"|sed 's/_$//g'
NAME-code_code2
NAME-code
NAME-code_code2_code3
bash$>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [string substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html),
something like:

```
for i in NAME-code_code2_L001_sufix NAME-code_L001_sufix_sufix2_sufix3 NAME-code_code2_code3_L001_sufix_sufix2_sufix3
do
    echo ${i%_L001*}
done
```